# lowest value in top 50%

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a King of the Hill/Elimination bracket spreadsheet & I have a cell that I want to return the cut (last score in the top 50%). Would anyone know how to go about this?

I have a formula for the average of the range, excluding 0's, but that isnt accurate since it isnt actually showing the lowest score. =AVERAGEIF(F9:G667,"<>0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is "percentile".  Excel's percentile function interpolates, so I'm not sure it's appropriate for your use case.

See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/percentile-function-91b43a53-543c-4708-93de-d626debdddca

At the very least, you can compute the percentile, then take the minimum score of all values filtered to be above the interpolated 50th percentile.

Here's a slightly clever implementation:

Assume your data is in the range `C2:C11`.

In `c13`, we'll compute the 50th percentile as `=PERCENTILE(C2:C11, 0.5)`
In column `d`, we'll use an `IF` statement to either select the adjacent value from column `c`, or a very large number, depending on whether the value is greater than the percentile. E.g., `=IF(C2 > $C$13,C2,400000)`

Now we can take the min of column `d`: `=MIN(D2:D11)`

The only clever bit is using a giant number when the value in column `c` is less than the percentile, so that it effectively becomes invisible to the min operation.

Comment: Hello & thank you for the quick response. I tried this, but due to spaces being in the data, it is just returning a value of 0.

Comment: Actually, I just tried a test with a range of 10 cells(1-10) and it returned "5.5", when the number i would be looking for is 5, as that is the bottom number in the top 50 percentile.

Comment: Hmm. the zeros in your data are problematic.  "median" is also defined as '50th percentile' but excel's implementation of median interpolates as well.  I'll delete this answer so that more people will look at your question.

Answer (score 0):

The last score in the top 50% is the *k*th largest item where *k* is the number of items divided by 2.  Excel has a useful function called `LARGE`, which returns the *k*th largest item.  It also have an even *more* useful function called `AGGREGATE` which lets you do things like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVERAGE`, `LARGE`, `SMALL`, etc - but skips hidden rows or Error Values.

So, to get the *k*th item of the list (ignoring Error Values) we would use `=AGGREGATE(15, 6, F9:G667, k)` - of course, this is not going to skip `0`, because `0` is not an error.  But, you know what is?  **Divide by 0**.  So, if we do `F9*F9/F9`, then we will either get `F9` (for *F9<>0*) or the *#DIV/0!* error.

This now means our function is `=AGGREGATE(15, 6, F9:G667*F9:G667/F9:G667, k)`, but we still need to decide on a value for *k*.  Well, if we have 3 items then we want the 2nd one, if we have 6 items then we want the 6rd one - so, for *n* items we want item *n*÷2, rounded up.  Well, that's what the `ROUNDUP` function is for!

Still, we need to know what *n* is - but that's simple.  It's just the number of non-0 items in the list, or `COUNTIF(F9:G667,"<>0")` (Or ">0" if your list cannot contain negative numbers)

Plug it all together, and we get this:

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, F9:G667*F9:G667/F9:G667, ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(F9:G667,"<>0"), 0))
```